# Number of Four letter words

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many different four letter words can be formed (the words need not be meaningful) using the letters of the word PACIFIC such that the first letter is P and the last letter is F?

Comment: Permute the word ACIIC and notice that there are two duplicates (i.e. double C and I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P _ _ F

**If repetition is allowed**

Letters available to fill the space are P, A, C, I and F. (Doppelgangers of C and I don't matter)

Total number of arrangements = $5 \times5=25$

**If repetition is NOT allowed**

Letters available for arrangement are A,C,C,I and I. (P and F are already used)

First, let's consider only A, C and I.

Number of arrangements = $3\times2=6$

And there are other 2 cases are where letters 'C' and 'I' repeat twice in each respective case.

So, total number of arrangements = $8$

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot repeat the letters, you have 6 possible words.

You ask for 4 letters words, but conditional to have P as first and F as last letter. This leaves 2 spaces to fill. You have 5 different letters in PACIFIC, but removing P and F you get only 3. Then is $3*2 =6$

If you can repeat the letters, you still have 2 spaces, and 5 letters, which means $5*5=25$